# Oracle query running fine with SELECT * but 'hangs' with SELECT column1, column2

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query sent to me from developers and while trying to execute it I ran into some mysterious problem ( for me at least ).

```
SELECT h.toot_id, trunc(sysdate)
FROM  test.car_ehk h 
WHERE toot_id in
 (SELECT t.toot_id 
  FROM test.car_ehk e, 
       test.car t
  WHERE e.toot_id=t.toot_id 
    and t.toot_type_id < 8 
    and e.toot_ehk_id= 
     (SELECT max(toot_ehk_id) 
      FROM  test.car_ehk 
      WHERE toot_id = e.toot_id)
        and e.sent_lop_aeg is null 
        and t.alg_aeg <> e.sent_alg_aeg 
        and e.ehk_reply ='OK'
     )
    and toot_ehk_id =   
     (SELECT MAX(t2.TOOT_EHK_ID) 
      FROM test.car_EHK t2 
      WHERE TOOT_ID=H.TOOT_ID);
```

Doesn't work. Query just keeps on running and DBA had to kill it.

When I replace `select  h.toot_id, trunc(sysdate)` with `select h.*` it works.

How come?

Comment: is car_ehk or car sizeable tables that gets large amounts of data added or removed?  (I'm questioning if the table statistics are off which may result in a bad execution plan in some cases, and work fine in others)  I'm also struggling with what this is trying to do, it seems like there should be a better way to write this.  Can you explain in common English what this should do?  (Sample data w/ expected results would be great)

Comment: what happens when you remove `trunc(sysdate)` and keep only `h.toot_id` ?

Comment: If I leave only h.toot_id then nothing changes. 
Tables aren't that big, count(*) gives around 200k results. Tables contain multiple versions of entries for a car and the (select MAX(t2.toot_ehk_id)... stuff is trying to get the latest version.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like an Oracle bug to me. Perhaps look at the 'explain plan' for both statements. Validate any indexes used in one plan and not the other.

Comment: This is more appropriate as a comment than as an answer.